# How do I convert an integer to an enumerated type?

Tags: delphi, casting, integer, enumeration

I know how to convert an enumerated type to an integer.

```
type
  TMyType = (mtFirst, mtSecond, mtThird); 

var 
  ordValue:integer;
  enumValue:TMyType;
...
ordValue:= Ord(mtSecond); // result is 1
```

But how do I do the inverse operation and convert an integer to an enumerated type?

Comment: type
  TMyType = (mtFirst=1, mtSecond=2, mtThird=3); 

var 
  ordValue:integer;
  enumValue:TMyType;

ordValue:= Integer(mtSecond); // result is 2

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As Ken answered, you just cast it. But to make sure you have correct value you can use code like:

```
if (ordValue >= Ord(Low(TMyType))) and (ordValue <= Ord(High(TMyType))) then
    enunValue := TMyType(ordValue)
else 
    raise Exception.Create('ordValue out of TMyType range');
```

Comment: Oh you can use RTTI to get the allowable ranges and so tidy up this code

Comment: @KenWhite AFAIK one can cast any (out of range) value to enum and it wont raise exception - you have to write the range check yourself.

Comment: @ken what do you mean "automatically raise the exception"?

Comment: No, AFAIK the high bits (which are out of enum range) are just disregarded and you get "random" enum value. No exception when then using it.

Comment: @Ken I'm afraid ain has it right here. The only time that range checking code is emitted for enumerated types, that I am aware of, is when you perform arithmetic. And that means `inc` or `dec`.

Comment: @David - less known now are `Succ` and `Pred` functions.

Comment: @Serg Ah yes, of course, and they get caught by range checking too

Comment: @ain, `@David: I stand corrected. :) Deleting my comment as noise.

Comment: Yes, this snippet requires severe cleanup.

Comment: Beware when your enums are not contiguous.

Answer (score 21):

You can cast the integer by typecasting it to the enumerated type:

```
ordValue := Ord(mtSecond);
enumValue := TMyType(ordValue);
```

Answer (score 8):

Take care with casting because it requires full mapping with your ordinal type and integers. For example:

```
type Size = (Small = 2, Medium = 3, Huge = 10);
var sz: Size;
...
sz := Size(3); //means sz=Medium
sz := Size(7); //7 is in range but gives sz=outbound
```